# Updating mysql table columns using shell script

Tags: mysql

I need to update mysql table using shell script . It is failing . My script goes like below .

```
 #!/bin/bash
 set -x
 HOST=$1
 DB=$2
 FNAME=$3
 LNAME=$4
 FULLNAME="$FNAME $LNAME"
 #MYSQL="mysql -uroot -p'mypass' -h $HOST $DB"
 MYSQL="mysql -uroot -p'root123' -h $HOST $DB"
 echo $MYSQl
 $MYSQL -e 'INSERT INTO 'user' ('name', 'description', 'created_date',     'created_by') VALUES ( '$FNAME', '$FULLNAME', current_date(), 'dbo');
```

It is failing while running with mysql host, db, firstname and last name info as parameter .

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: Among other things, you have single quotes around table and column names.